# How to explode substrings inside a string in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a table like the one below

```
| Header 1  | Header 2  | Header 3       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                
| id1       | detail1   | <a@test.com> , <b@test.com> , <c@test.com>  , <d@test.com>
```

How do i explode it on SQL based on the substring emails inside the angle brackets such that it looks like the one below.

```
| Header 1  | Header 2   | Header 3.   |
-------------------------------------------
| id1       | detail1    | a@test.com  |
| id1       | detail1    | b@test.com  |
| id1       | detail1    | c@test.com  |
| id1       | detail1    | d@test.com  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`regexp_extract_all`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract_all) and [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#explode) should do.

```sql
select `Header 1`, `Header 2`, explode(regexp_extract_all(`Header 3`, '<(.+?)>')) as `Header 3` from table
```

this should get you

```
+--------+--------+----------+
|Header 1|Header 2|Header 3  |
+--------+--------+----------+
|id1     |detail1 |a@test.com|
|id1     |detail1 |b@test.com|
|id1     |detail1 |c@test.com|
|id1     |detail1 |d@test.com|
+--------+--------+----------+
```

Be aware that `regexp_extract_all` was added to spark since version `3.1.0`.

---

#### For spark blow `3.1.0`

This can be done with `split`, somewhat a dirty hack. But the strategy and the results are the same.

```
select `Header 1`, `Header 2`, explode(array_remove(split(`Header 3`, '[<>,\\s]+'), '')) as `Header 3` from table
```

What this do is to regex match the delimiters and split the string into array. It also needs an `array_remove` function call to remove unneeded empty string.

---

#### Explanation

With `regexp_extract_all`, we use the pattern `<(.+?)>` to extract all strings within angle brackets, into an array like this

```
['a@test.com', 'b@test.com', 'c@test.com']
```

For the pattern `(.+?)`here

- `.` matches 1 character;
- `+` is a quantifier of `.`, looking for 1 or unlimited matches;
- `?` is a non greedy modifier, makes the match stop as soon as possible;
- brackets makes the pattern with in angle brackets as a matching group, so we can extract from groups later;

Now with `explode`, we can separate elements of the array into multiple rows, hence the result above.

Comment: Thanks for the help! unfortunately, I am currently using v 3.0.1 so this hasn't been added yet. May I know how can i do this without regexp_extract_all?

Comment: @OscarLai Hi, I've edited my answer for spark below v3.1.0

Comment: If you've encounted regex matching problem in `\\s` using the split approach, try with `[<>,\\\\s]+`. This is a character escaping problem, depending on your environment.

Comment: thank you so much, so I tried your new method and it seems that there are new unintended columns being created also. so e.g., the email is <alpha_beta@gmail.com>. after explode the column created is alpha, _beta, alpha_beta@gmail.com . Tried both regex and this seems to happen for both

Comment: seems that it is also exploding the characters between the arrow brackets e.g, ` alpha <alpha@test.com>, beta <beta@test.com>, charlie <charlie@test.com> `  so the individual emails are exploded but so is the words between the angle brackets

Comment: @OscarLai The `split` approach is a bit rough, the regex expression used here needs to be tuned specifically for your data. If possible, I would recommend upgrading spark version, and there are more improvements in recent versions.